# Android Cling UPNP - cannot able to discover Local Devices

Tags: android, upnp, android-cling

I am using cling library to discover android devices on same local network (wifi). For that i have created two Local Device (`UDAServiceType = SwitchPower`) on two different android phones (PhoneA and PhoneB).

But when i execute this `upnpService.getControlPoint().search()` on PhoneA it only discover local device for phoneA and My PC Name connected to same wifi (`UDAServiceType = MediaPlayer`). but it doesn't discover any Local Device on other PhoneB. 
I have declared two services in my manifest file:

```
<service android:name="My_Package_Name".BrowserUpnpService"/>
<service android:name="<Library_PCKAGE_NAME>org.teleal.cling.android.AndroidUpnpServiceImpl"/>
```

Well i think the issue is: instead of creating LOCAL DEVICE and binding it with a LOCAL SERVICE i should create a REMOTE DEVICE and BIND IT WITH REMOTE SERVICE? if yes? then how i can i do that. 
Also i am following this link [Cling on Android](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/core/manual/cling-core-manual.html#chapter.Android).

What i am trying to do is broadcast (IP, deviceName, Port, devicePort, serviceName, deviceType) the device and discover the devices connected to a local network (wifi).

Comment: try to study their upnpBrowser demo app u'll get some idea

Comment: @r4jiv007. i have implemented that demo.. it doesn't discover devices registered on other phone..

Comment: well, its working for me !! i even wrote another demo based on it!!

Comment: ahan.. but just to make sure.. now u can search the devices registered in one demo from other demo, right? if so then may be my smart phone model plays some role here.. :/

Comment: it can be issue with your router also !! it must support multicast for it to work

Comment: Do you have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @TaimurButt, i too have same issue. Did you get any solution for this?